# How to parse xml with js or jquery, when fields are not known in advance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have been searching for the past hour and have not found a solution that is well suited to my situation. I have an event registration form and in order for users to have the form auto populated they can specify an id from a previous registration. There are over 20 fields.

Everything is working pretty well. I have a PHP script that creates an xml response for ajax. The xml is of form

```
<response>
    <field1>f1</field1>
    <field1>f2</field1>
    etc
</response>
```

My javascript is

```
       $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "myscript.php",
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(xml){
                    $("#field1").val($("field1",xml).text());
                    $("#field2").val($("field2",xml).text());
            }
        })
```

Above works fine but I don't want to manually write out each form field assignment. I want to do it in a loop. So something like this in the success function:

```
 var fields= xmlResponse.getElementsByTagName("response");
 for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
          // not sure what to put here...
 }
```

In the for loop I have to index in to the node name and value so that I can simply have a statement that would be of this form: $("#"+fields[i].nodename).val($(fields[i].nodevalue,xml).text());

I tried

```
$("#" + fields[0].childNodes[i]).val(fields[0].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
```

But that did not return the values.

Any idea on how best to do this? I feel like I am very close to having this working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.parseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), and then loop over the elements with `.each()`.

```
var $xml = $.parseXML(xml);
$("#response", xml).children().each(function(i, e) {
    var field = e.tagName;
    var value = e.innerHTML;
    $("#" + field).val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. What it comes down to is that when you parse an XML file, the parser doesn't care what the fields are, it'll parse it as it sees it. You would basically have to tell the script to pull certain tags with certain text. As far as I know, this is best done using the .tagName property and the tag's value and storing it in an object.

```
var data={}
$(this).children().each(function() {
    data[this.tagName]=$(this).text();
})
```

You can see how this would work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dpK7x/1/

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. But in the my php script I had to remove the header('Content-type: text/xml') call. It seems that with that call the xml variable returned to the ajax call is a different data type than what your code expects. Again, thanks!